# envio de informacion mediante metodo post no funciona en imap

Tags: php, email, imap

mi código para ver el contenido de mi correo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$username = 'micorreo@outlook.com';
$password = 'micontraseña';
$server = '{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}';
$connection = imap_open($server, $username, $password);
$mailboxes = imap_list($connection, $server,'*');
print_r(imap_errors());
print_r($mailboxes);
imap_close($connection);
?>
```

y obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
Array ( [0] => {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}
Archive [1] => {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}
Deleted [2] => {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}
Drafts [3] => {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}
Inbox [4] => {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}
Junk [5] => {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}
Notes [6] => {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}
Outbox [7] => {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}Sent )
```

Estoy probando con enviar el correo y la contraseña mediante de un formulario asi pero obtengo

```
Array ( [0] => IMAP Authentication cancelled )
```

eso usando el siguiente código

```
        <?php

    $username = $_POST['correo'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $server = '{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}';
    $connection = imap_open($server, $username, $password);
    $mailboxes = imap_list($connection, $server,'*');
    print_r(imap_errors());
    print_r($mailboxes);
    imap_close($connection);

        ?>
```

lo estoy haciendo de forma local con apache, xampp la ultima version de php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione cambiando la siguiente linea

```
$server = '{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}';
```

por lo siguiente:

```
$server = '{pop3.live.com}';
```

Ahora si puedo usar un formulario para ver mi correo solo que la respuesta cambio a

```
Array ( [0] => {pop3.live.com}
Archive [1] => {pop3.live.com}
Deleted [2] => {pop3.live.com}
Drafts [3] => {pop3.live.com}
Inbox [4] => {pop3.live.com}
Junk [5] => {pop3.live.com}
Notes [6] => {pop3.live.com}
Outbox [7] => {pop3.live.com}Sent )
```